# Pinning the end points in a d3 force directed graph

Tags: d3.js

I have an application that generates a d3 display using the force-directed layout. One of capabilities in the application is to show all paths from vertex A to vertex B. I want to pin the start and end vertices to the left and right edges of the display and I've accomplished this programmatically, but I'm not happy with results as the force directed layout clumps all of the remaining vertices in the middle of the graph div. Changing the gravity and the link strength parameters to the force directed layout simply changes the size of the clump in the middle of the screen.

Any suggestions on how I can distribute the middle vertices more uniformly between the two pinned endpoints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The jsfiddle is here: ["d3 path example"](http://jsfiddle.net/djhallx/6n78y0kt/)